# How to debug unmanaged code in .NET Windows Service?

Tags: .net, debugging, com, windows-services, interop

I have been developing a VB.Net windows service for some time now. It uses a COM class developed in C++.

I haven't been able to use it as a true service because I was using an unregistered 3rd party control that shows a nag screen, so the service crashed. Management finally bought it yesterday, so I've just begun to test it in service mode.

Some time ago I used to debug c++ windows services with a call to DebugBreak() at the beginning of the application. 
For .NET I have found this:
[How to debug a windows service using breakpoints?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761120/how-to-debug-a-windows-service-using-breakpoints)

So far, so good; but there's a method call on the COM Object that is failing with error code 0x80004003 when running in service mode, but it works correctly as an application.

The problem is that I'm unable to debug the COM code. If I load a cpp from it in my vs session and put a breakpoint, it's ignored because there are no symbols loaded, even after the COM object is created. If I put a DebugBreak in the C++ code, it raises an exception in .Net, but doesn't ask me to debug the code. In the service project, "Enable unmanaged code debugging" is checked.

I have also tried to use the COM class project, but with no success.

Any idea?

**Edit - 2011-01-03:** To answer Chris O questions, yes, I can run the process as SYSTEM, but, how would that help me? If everything works as SYSTEM then that's because I need some permissions?

And yes, I am able to attach the debugger to the process, with the limitations stated above: In the "attach to process" dialog from Visual Studio 2005, the service doesn't appear in the process list, so I have to use a Debug.Assert call or similar methods. Also, I'm only able to debug the .Net code; I can't debug native code.

Comment: Can you run your service as SYSTEM, instead of LOCAL SERVICE?  This is not a real solution but might tell if this user is missing some privilege.

Comment: Also, are you able to successfully attach the debugger to your running service process?  If not then you will have to use remote debugging, http://blogs.technet.com/b/marcelofartura/archive/2007/08/09/how-to-attach-a-debugger-from-the-creation-time-of-the-worker-process-w3wp-exe.aspx has some advice at the bottom of the webpage for remote debugging.

Comment: Short answers, yes, and yes. Details in the question body.

Comment: How about create an account for the service and give proper permissions.  Then set the service to use that account.  I would then revoke windows login permissions on that account.

Comment: I don't think your going to find a way to debug the native code.  Short of actually working with the company you bought the code from to locate the issue.

Comment: @Zman101: The native code I'm trying to debug is mine. I guessed I messed up my explanation giving unnecessary details about another 3rd party component (which is for .Net, BTW). I will try to create an account with proper permissions when I find some time, thank you for your comment!